# Map an entity in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How about, I have a problem and it is before in symfony3 was run in the console:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import MiBundle yml
```

and generated and map an entity of the database but in Symfony 4 the command in the console is always the same, but the bundles are no longer occupied in the latest version so the previous command as it is does not work anymore, Someone could help me...

likewise generate the get and set

Answer (score 1):

When using the new Symfony 4 directory structure without bundles the commands for importing the mapping and creating entities from an existing schema in the DoctrineBundle will no longer work properly. There is currently an ongoing discussion whether to update them, but the Doctrine team considers those tools counterproductive. You are not meant to blindly map the schema 1:1 to your domain model.

The best advice I can give for now is to temporarily create a bundle and then move the resulting files. This is also the workaround suggested in the github-issue regarding this: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/729

The Symfony team is moving some of those commands into their own [MakeBundle](https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle), but I don't think this command is already in there. Maybe you want to follow their progress.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment was very helpful